# Read the Axis2 output from client (Stub)

Tags: apache-axis

I am getting value till `toEnvelope` method. when I try to read from `axisclient(WS client)`
am getting `null` value.

```
System.out.println("toEnvelope :"+param.getOTA_VehCancelRSSequence_type0().getVehCancelRSCore().getUniqueID().getID());
org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope emptyEnvelope = factory.getDefaultEnvelope();
```

Please help me to over come this

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last [OperationContext](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/context/OperationContext.html) using the `getLastOperationContext()` method from the client.

**For outgoing messages:**

```
OperationContext operationContext = stub._getServiceClient().getLastOperationContext();
if (operationContext != null) {

    MessageContext outMsgContext = operationContext.getMessageContext("Out");
    if (outMsgContext != null) {
        System.out.println("Out SOAP Message : "+outMsgContext.getEnvelope().toString());
    }       

}
```

**For incoming messages:**

```
OperationContext operationContext = stub._getServiceClient().getLastOperationContext();
if (operationContext != null) {

    MessageContext inMsgContext = operationContext.getMessageContext("In");
    if (inMsgContext != null) {
        System.out.println("Received SOAP Message: "+ inMsgContext.getEnvelope().toString());
    }

}
```